GLMM with log-Gaussian, log-Gamma
I need someone smarter than I am to look at this problem, and I'd appreciate it if you'd take the time. So, I am trying to predict reaction times here in a glmm using a battery of IVs. You can see the exact formula down below. Let's have a look at the DV first.
Here's a plot of the DV, reaction times, overlayed with a lognormal distribution in red, showing pretty good fit:

A gof test also finds that lognormal is the best theoretical fit for the data:
Goodness-of-fit statistics
                             1-mle-norm 2-mle-lnorm 3-mle-gamma
Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic  0.2027394  0.06692527  0.07747488
Cramer-von Mises statistic   55.4388774  3.84932050  6.05656030
Anderson-Darling statistic          Inf 22.20873772 37.23956856

Goodness-of-fit criteria
                               1-mle-norm 2-mle-lnorm 3-mle-gamma
Akaike's Information Criterion   18737.57    14175.37    14600.17
Bayesian Information Criterion   18750.01    14187.81    14612.61

Now, to the problem. I have read in a couple of threads and in scientific literature as well that using a log-Gaussian with a Gaussian family and log-link is the way to go here, if the data shows a lognormal distribution.
This, however, shows model fit statistics which are closer to the AIC and BIC numbers of the normal distribution than the lognormal distribution:
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: gaussian  ( log )
Formula: rt ~ n_drones + Gender + Age + Videogames + norm_time_group +  
    Objektname + nb_drone + Entscheidungsprüfung + (1 + n_drones |      VP)
   Data: sdt_roh

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 17959.2  18145.8  -8949.6  17899.2     3691 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.6632 -0.3949 -0.1687  0.1132 16.1840 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr          
 VP       (Intercept) 0.0000   0.0000                 
          n_drones2   0.6494   0.8058    NaN          
          n_drones3   0.8688   0.9321    NaN 0.82     
          n_drones4   0.6333   0.7958    NaN 0.80 0.76
 Residual             6.7428   2.5967                 
Number of obs: 3721, groups:  VP, 21

I have stumbled upon the glmmTMB package, which in theory allows you to specify a lognormal family explicity, but if I try to use it, I encounter an error. I think this is how the function is supposed to be used. Please, correct me if I'm wrong. I have tried this in all kinds of variations with different links and without any link, but all attempts failed:
> glmm_rt_drones <- glmmTMB(
+    rt ~ n_drones + Gender + Age + Videogames + norm_time_group + Objektname + nb_drone + Entscheidungsprüfung +
+      (1 + n_drones | VP), 
+    family = lognormal(link = "log"), 
+   data = sdt_roh)
Error in lognormal(link = "log") : unused argument (link = "log")

I have also tried using a log-Gamma distribution, which works a lot better than the log-Gaussian:
 Family: Gamma  ( log )
Formula:          rt ~ n_drones + Gender + Age + Videogames + norm_time_group +  
    Objektname + nb_drone + Entscheidungsprüfung + (1 + n_drones |      VP)
Data: sdt_roh

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 12361.9  12548.5  -6150.9  12301.9     3691 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr              
 VP     (Intercept) 0.06673  0.2583                     
        n_drones2   0.05299  0.2302   -0.35             
        n_drones3   0.01447  0.1203    0.38  0.16       
        n_drones4   0.04731  0.2175   -0.44  0.42  0.38 
Number of obs: 3721, groups:  VP, 21

Dispersion estimate for Gamma family (sigma^2): 0.367 

My Questions are:

What exactly is the difference between a log-Gaussian and the lognormal family in glmmTMB?
When do I use which of them?
Is a log-Gamma model more robust with positive right-skewing data? I've already build a couple of glmms with this type of data and a log-Gamma always proved to produce more stable and better fitted models.
follow-up question down below...

Any help would be much appreciated. Hope everybody has a great day and thanks for replies!
EDIT:
Ok, I could fix the issue now by restarting the session and only requiring glmmTMB. It seems like there was interference by another package. Thanks for the hint!
The output of the model raises another question for me. I have experienced it a couple of times now that a gof test will show a lognormal distribution, but a glmm with log-gamma works better than with lognormal distribution, causing less convergence problems and better fit. What is it about gamma, that works better than lognormal, even if the latter is a better fit to the DV?
1: In finalizeTMB(TMBStruc, obj, fit, h, data.tmb.old) :
  Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')
2: In finalizeTMB(TMBStruc, obj, fit, h, data.tmb.old) :
  Model convergence problem; singular convergence (7). See vignette('troubleshooting'), help('diagnose')

 Family: lognormal  ( log )
Formula:          rt ~ n_drones + Gender + Age + Videogames + norm_time_group +  
    Objektname + nb_drone + Entscheidungsprüfung + (1 + n_drones |      VP)
Data: sdt_roh

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
      NA       NA       NA       NA     3691 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr              
 VP     (Intercept) 0.039902 0.19975                    
        n_drones2   0.009494 0.09744  -0.84             
        n_drones3   0.002173 0.04661  -0.71  0.94       
        n_drones4   0.012651 0.11248  -0.72  0.75  0.87 
Number of obs: 3721, groups:  VP, 21

Dispersion parameter for lognormal family (): 1.77 


I'm not sure if this is a bug or you have something else in your namespace, but my version of glmmTMB::lognormal defaults to link="log" so you could just try leaving out that argument. See here for some good discussion about log-transforming your response versus a log-linked GLM, which is possibly what you mean by your first question.

Yeah, I have tried it both with and without the link argument.
family = lognormal,
family = lognormal(),
without a link function both throw:
Error in family$ family : $ operator not defined for this S4 class

That sounds like a programming issue then (and off-topic here), because for me any of those options work fine.

Ok yeah I solved that issue, but the thread you linked to is about transforming the outcome variable. That was not my question. The question was about different family distributions for a glmm! Have edited the initial post with a follow up question as well...
